# removeChild is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, removechild

```
window.onload = initPage;
var firstname = false;
var lastname = false;

function initPage() {
    addEventHandler(document.getElementById("firstname"), "blur", verifyFirst);
    addEventHandler(document.getElementById("lastname"), "blur", verifyLast);
    addEventHandler(document.getElementById("submit"), "click", showName);
}

function verifyFirst(e) {
    var me = getActivatedObject(e);
    if (me.value === "") {
        me.className = "error";
        me.focus();
        me.select();
        return;
    }
    else {
        me.className = "";
        firstname = true;
        enabledButton();
    }
}

function verifyLast(e) {
    var me = getActivatedObject(e);
    if (me.value === "") {
        me.className = "error";
        me.focus();
        me.select();
        return;
    }
    else {
        me.className = "";
        lastname = true;
        enabledButton();
    }
}

function enabledButton() {
    if (firstname && lastname) {
        document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
    }
}

function showName() {
    var first = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
    var last = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
    var word = first.toLowerCase() + last.toLowerCase();
    for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        var letter = word.charAt(i);
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.setAttribute("src", "images/" + letter + ".png");
        img.setAttribute("style", "left:" + 50 * i);
        document.getElementById("displayname").appendChild(img);
    }
    var t = setInterval(removeName, 2000);
}

function removeName() {
    var display = document.getElementById("displayname").getElementsByTagName("img");
    var lengthOfDisplay = display.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < lengthOfDisplay; i++) {
        document.getElementById("displayname").removeChild(display[i]);
    }
    var t = setInterval(showName, 2000);
}
```

This is my current code that I am working on.  I am creating a website with two input fields for first name and last name.  On blur of each field after they are verified they will enabled the submit button.  When the submit button is clicked, it will combine the first and last name and then separate each letter and call an image that will relate to each letter entered and display it on the displayname div.

Here is where I get the problem:

What I want is to display the image then remove the images and display it again continuously using setInterval. (i.e. the name spelled with the images will be flashing).  unfortunately with my code when I try to remove the images using the removeChild function, I get an error of:

**UPDATE**

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Below is an image of the of the inspection tool with the error and line that is getting the error.

[image: error image]

Why am I getting this error when I am asking it to remove the images with removeChild(display[i])?

Comment: Missing `)` in fragment `getElementById("displayname".removeChild`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace line 68 with

```
document.getElementById("displayname").innerHTML = '';
```

Comment: Looks like this fixed my code.  Such a simple correction yet I couldn't figure it out. I guess I was too much into Nodes that i forgot about this simple code. Thank you.  Now I just have to fix the setInterval part of my code to time it out so that it times out nicely and doesn't display the name twice every now and then.

Comment: This will remove everything from `#displayname` while OP's code removes only `img` nodes. And if OP does want to remove everything, there's no need for the `for` loop on line 67 either.

Answer (score 2):

Change the code on the line 68 from this

```
document.getElementById("displayname".removeChild(display[i]));
```

to this

```
document.getElementById("displayname").removeChild(display[i]);
```

Comment: Updated with new error.  Sorry. I was trying to fix my code while writing this post and I guess I made a small syntax error.  This is the actual Error that I am getting that I have been stuck on.

Answer (score 0):

`removeChild()` is a method applicable to a Node (and not a string or a selector as you have used in your code).

`document.getElementById("displayname").removeChild(display[i]));` should be the appropriate syntax.

Comment: Updated with new error after that small syntax error. Sorry about that. This is the actual Error that I was looking into. While fixing it I guess I made a mistake and got a syntax error.