# Scrape an innertext from Wikipedia's infobox

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, wikipedia

Doing a project that requires using a command button should extract some info from a webpage.
I chose to have 'Confirmed Cases' from Wikipedia's infobox of the [COVID-19 pandemic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19_pandemic), I can't seem to write the correct "getElementsBy.." to have the info extracted.

```
 Private Sub AccesswebsitePAN_Click()
WB_PAN.Navigate ("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19_pandemic")
End Sub

Private Sub GetinfoPAN_Click()
Cells(2, 1).Value = WB_PAN.Document.getElementsById("mw-content-text").getElementsByClassName("mw-parser-output").getElementsByTagName("table").getElementsByTagName("tbody").getElementsByTagName("tr")(12).getElementsByTagName("td")(0).Innertext
End Sub

Private Sub WB_PAN_StatusTextChange(ByVal Text As String)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You have neglected at several stages to index into collections returned by `getElementsBy` methods. Also, it is `getElementById`. I might go for a more readable shorter path that selects the table by its class (using querySelector) then use the .rows method.

Your way:

```
Debug.Print WB_PAN.Document.getElementById("mw-content-text").getElementsByClassName("mw-parser-output")(0).getElementsByTagName("table")(0).getElementsByTagName("tbody")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")(18).getElementsByTagName("td")(0).Innertext
```

---

Alternative:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CovidCases()

    Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19_pandemic"

        While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend

        Debug.Print .Document.querySelector(".infobox").Rows(12).innertext
        Debug.Print .Document.querySelector(".infobox").Rows(12).firstchild.nextsibling.innertext
    
        .Quit
    End With
    
End Sub
```

---

Slightly cleaner is to clear out, using an approach from [user4596341](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40969054/6241235), the node html that adds the lagging [4] reference before taking your cases, such that you have a more readable path

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CovidCases()

    Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19_pandemic"

        While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend

        .Document.querySelector(".infobox tr:nth-of-type(13) sup").innerHTML = vbNullString
        
        Debug.Print .Document.querySelector(".infobox").Rows(12).Cells(1).innertext
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Seeing @Sim's answer reminded me you can walk back up the DOM to get just the case count which is even cleaner:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CovidCases()

    Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19_pandemic"

        While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend

        Debug.Print .Document.querySelector(".infobox tr:nth-of-type(13) sup").PreviousSibling.NodeValue
    
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What an approach `.querySelector().innerHTML = vbNullString`!!! Gonna save it for future use.

Answer (score 1):

As ID is a unique locator, you can try using the same within your script to fetch the result.

```
Option Explicit
Sub GetCaseCount()
    Const Url$ = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19_pandemic"
    Dim Http As Object, elem As Object, S$
    
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", Url, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36"
        .send
        S = .responseText
    End With
    
    With CreateObject("htmlfile")
        .body.innerHTML = S
    
        Set elem = .getElementById("cite_ref-JHU_ticker_5-0")
        Debug.Print elem.ParentNode.innerText
    End With
End Sub
```

The script should work without adding any reference to the library.